# What scriptures describe using Red Arsenic for invisibility?

Tags: practice, yoga, siddhi, plants

Adinatha's Khechari Vidya is an early Hatha Yoga text dated to the 15th century.  [This excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNGzq.jpg) from the Khechari Vidya describes various Siddhis or magical powers that can be obtained by a Yogic practice involving the tongue:

> The best adept quickly attains absolutely all magical powers that are found in the three worlds, such as magical sandals, the magical sword, power over zombies, magical elixirs, **realgar**, invisibility, access to the treasures of the subterranean realms, and power over male and female genies.

I'm interested in the magic achieved through realgar, which is another word for [red arsenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realgar).  Here is what the translator says in a footnote:

> Realgar (manahsila) is red arsenic, an ingredient in elixirs[.]... [A] Budhhist Kriyatantra, the Amoghapashakalparaja, describes how manahsila, when applied to the eyes, can make the wearer invisible and able to move in the ether[.]... Cf. Kamasutra 7.2.46, in which it is said that if one coats one's hand with the faeces of a peacock that has eaten haritala and/or manahsila and touches something, it becomes invisible.

First of all, I wasn't able to track down that statement in the Kama Sutra, although for obvious reasons I didn't look very thoroughly.  But my question is, what scriptures describe using red arsenic to make yourself or other objects invisible?

Buddhist texts like the Amoghapashakalparaja may discuss it, but I want to know what Hindu scripture has to say on the subject.

Comment: The only place i know where Manahsila is recounted is when Sita tells Hanuman how Rama had applied it on her face. And she doesn't talk about any invisibility there. So I doubt the claim your question makes.

Comment: Neither Hatha yoga nor the Kama Sutra are part of the Hindu religion. They may be claimed as part of Indian culture, but not of the Vedanta.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Yes, I agree with you that Hatha Yoga texts aren't authentic Hindu scriptures.  That's why I posted this question, to find out whether Hindu scripture backs up this claim.

Comment: I request you once again to not share  or seek information on magic. It is dangerous and one must exercise some sense of responsibility while seeking it.  The ultimate goal and state of knowledge is being passed on. However, it should be sought from the right people, by the right people and should be passed on to the right people.

Comment: texts do not use the phrase "Hatha yoga", but their verses describe exercises and postures (asanas) that appear in later yoga texts, .For example, the Agama texts of Vaishnavism called Pancaratrika teach non-seated asanas such as mayurasana in section 96 of Vimanarcanakalpa patala , section 1.21-22 of Padma samhita yogapada and section 12.31-37 of Ahirbudhnya samhita.[12] According to Nicholas Tarling, the Pancaratrika doctrines crystallized by the first two centuries of the common era.[14] Gerald Larson and other scholars date the yoga-containing Pancaratra text Ahirbudhnya Samhita

Comment: Nishva satattva samhita of Shaivism, Agamas and the various Puranas of Vaishnavism, Shaivism and Shaktism, which do not use the phrase Hatha yoga, but teach asanas, mudras and meditation found in later Hatha yoga literature.

Comment: @moonstar2001 i may share soon.

Comment: Vashistha samhita (IAST: Vasiṣṭha saṃhitā), a Vedanta and Vaishnava Hindu text composed before 1300 CE, teaches asanas, pranayama and also incorporates Kundalini yoga. It, however, skips the discussion of mudras

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Everything and anything is virtually part of Hinduism what to say of something like Hatha Yoga, Kriya Yoga etc?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yes asanas, mudras are important parts of Sadhana. And there are many many Agamas that talk about them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This book [Goddess Traditions in Tantric Hinduism](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=GPiPCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=manahsila%20invisibility&source=bl&ots=gn4cMdhQow&sig=XuGoRHSbqMERehHnMaOJzokNhkU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj71Pqyu-3TAhVGpo8KHeHPAM4Q6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q&f=false) makes a reference to a procedure in the Brahmayamala Tantra.

[image]

According to an [exoticindiaart description](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/brahmayamala-tantra-or-picumata-religious-observances-and-sexual-ritual-of-tantric-practitioner-chapter-3-21-and-45-NAK612/) Brahma Yamala Tantra is one of the oldest Bhairava Tantras and Kasmira Shaivaite Abhinavagupta has cited from this text in his Tantraloka. Moreover even some Buddhist Tantra scriptures like Laghusarprava contain extensive passages that are borrowed from this tantra.

I wasn't able to get a direct source to this tantra since I couldn't find anything on the net. If anybody else has a more reliable answer please feel free to contribute.